# store.getState is not a function even though it's on the object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4

So I know others have asked similar questions but the cases are a little different. I'm trying to check if the user is authenticated or not in state when accessing a private route, and I've set up my private route wrapper like so:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, store: store, ...rest }: { component: any, store: Store<ApplicationState>, path: any }) => (
      <Route {...rest} render={(props:ReduxRouteComponentProps) => (
         store.getState().authenticationState.authenticated ? (
            <Component {...props}/>
         ) : (
            <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { from: props.location }
            }}/>
         )
      )}/>
);
```

PrivateRoute gets the store passed as a prop from the root component.

When debugging, I get the `store.getState is not a function` error, but when hovering over the store argument, I can see that at least the Chrome debugger *thinks* it is.

[image: Lookin good]

[image: What the dickens?!?]

The hell is going on?

**EDIT: PrivateRoute Usage**

I've been asked to show where the private route is being used -- here are some snippets:

```
// Navigation Frame

    export class NavigationFrame extends React.Component<INavigationFrameProps, {}> {
        render() {
            console.log(this)
            return <Router>
                      <div className="navigation-frame">
                      <Route exact path="/" component={Splash}/>
                      <Route exact path="/register" component={RegistrationForm}/>
                      <Route path="/signin" component={SignInContainer}/>
                      <PrivateRoute store={this.props.store} path="/i" component={AuthenticatedView}/>
                      </div>
                   </Router>;
        }
    }
```

and the provider tag...

```
// main.tsx

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App name="my-app" />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("react-app")
);
```

**EDIT: Asked why I don't map the store to props...**

Do you mean something like this? The following throws errors for me saying PrivateRoute is an incompatible type for `connect`

```
let getAuthState = (state: AuthenticationState) => {
   return state;
 }

 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch:any) => {
    return {}
 }

 const mapStateToProps = (state: ApplicationState) => {
   return {
     authState: getAuthState(state.authenticationState)
   }
 }

 export const PrivateRouteContainer = connect(
   mapStateToProps,
   mapDispatchToProps
 )(PrivateRoute);
```

Comment: Can you post the code that uses `PrivateRoute`?

Comment: Any reason why you are not mapping the `authenticateState` to your component props? Did you check through the react dev tools as well?

Comment: Won't this.state.authenticationState work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lord. I figured it out: **This works:**

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: { component: any, store: {store:Store<ApplicationState>}, path: any }) => {
   return(rest.store.store.getState().authenticationState.authenticated ?
      <Route {...rest}
        render={(props:any) => (
            <Component {...props}/>
         )} /> : <Route {...rest}
        render={(props: any) => (
            <Redirect to={{
              pathname: '/signin',
              state: { from: props.location }
              }}/>

      )} />
   )};
```

Note I end up accessing a store object... on the store... It's an artifact of passing dynamic properties as a single package.